# Error on creating connection to PDO in PHP

Tags: php, pdo, lampp

Today, I removed and reinstalled the latest version of lampp in order to move to php 5.30, and suddenly a very simple app is failing to connect to the mysql database.  I'm using PDO to connect, and receiving the following error:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] Invalid argument (trying to connect 
via unix://) in /home/raistlin/www/todoapp/home.php on line 9

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
Invalid argument' in /home/raistlin/www/todoapp/home.php:9 Stack trace: #0
/home/raistlin/www/todoapp/home.php(9): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'USER', 
'PASSWORD') #1 {main} thrown in /home/raistlin/www/todoapp/home.php on line 9
```

I am not catching the error at the moment, for the sake of debugging it.

The following code is enough to replicate the issue on my system:

```
<?php
$DBACCESS = array(
    "connstring"=>"mysql:host=localhost;dbname=todoapp",
    "host"=>"localhost",
    "user"=>"user",
    "password"=>"password",
    "todoapp"=>"todoapp"
    );

    echo implode('<br \>',$DBACCESS);

    $dbh = new PDO($DBACCESS['connstring'],$DBACCESS['user'],$DBACCESS['password']);

    $dbh = null;
?>
```

Looking online, I've found one or two other people with the same issue, but none of them have received a response, much less a working one.  Does anyone know what is happening?  Is there something I missed in the configuration?  What do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Usually means that you need to specify TCP/IP (1), or tell MySQL where your Unix socket is (2):

1. "mysql:host=127.0.0.1" or "mysql:host=localhost;port=3306"
2. "mysql:unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"

Comment: I'm not sure why MySQL sometimes takes "localhost" to mean "I'm going to use a Unix socket"

Comment: Perfect. The problem was solved with option 2, although with the xampp lampp installation, I needed to use /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock.

Comment: Sure. Glad you were able to find the socket - I just threw an example in there and prayed you'd find it. :)

Comment: Same problem here too. @krdluzni, seeing your comment I just did this: 

`pdo_mysql.default_socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock` 

in the /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini file, and it worked.

I would otherwise be wondering what configuration error I must have made in Zend Framework. So thanks for posting this!

Comment: Simply add port in you settings like `'host'      => env('DB_HOST', '192.168.1.165'), 'port'      => env('DB_PORT', '3317'),` `instead` defining 192.168.1.165:3317

Comment: I don't have php.ini file in my magento root directory. What should I do? Can anyone please suggest me?

Comment: @Exception use `<?php phpinfo();` to see what `Loaded Configuration File` is; that's where your php.ini is located.

Comment: @TML: Thanks for reply. I have used that function and I got this path: /usr/local/lib/php.ini
But I am not able to find usr directory in magento installation. Would it be somewhere else?

Comment: @Exception it's in the root of the filesystem; you should speak with your Systems Admin/vendor for help on configuring this.

Comment: @TML: Thanx for the help!!

Answer (score 24):

You can also use 127.0.0.1, rather than specifying "localhost", in your db connection string to avoid this issue altogether.

Comment: The accepted answer is for sysadmins, this one is for developers ;) thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You might want to modify php.ini so PDO can find mysql.sock by specifying the `pdo_mysql.default_socket = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock` (in the case of xampp). Don't forget to restart Apache after changing php.ini.

(Sorry, this seems to be a repeated solution).

Answer (score 4):

I'm using MAMP 2.0.1 and Symfony 1.4 with Doctrine for this project.

Third option worked for me with a small modification:
in /config/databases.yml

```
dsn: 'mysql:unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock;dbname=MY_DB_NAME;'
```

Answer (score 2):

The most common cause of an error like this would be that MySQL isn’t running.

Comment: I've checked that, already.  Even to the point of shutting it down and restarting it.

Comment: How do you know it’s the *most common*?